# have script wait until mailbox is backedup

Tags: powershell, backup, exchange-server

I have built a function in powershell that will backup an exchange mailbox. In Simplistic terms...

New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -FilePath "$MailboxBackupLocation\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(FULL).pst"

This works great, however I have one other small problem. I need to next run the powershell command to delete the user out of exchange.

What I need is for the powershell script to wait on each mailbox it is backing up until it is completed, before moving on to the next mailbox.... or at least hold the function up from completing until all mailbox backups are complete....

Oh and if it can show progress that would be great.

```
    function Backup-Mailbox
{
    Param 
        (
            $LogFileRequest = "",
            #$User = 'mdgeorge',
            #[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            #[ValidateSet('UPN','Email')]
            $MailBoxIdentity,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [ValidateSet('Full','Inbox','SentItems','DeletedItems','Calendar','Contacts','Drafts','Journal','Tasks','Notes','JunkEmail','CommunicationHistory','Voicemail','Fax','Conflicts','SyncIssues','LocalFailures','ServerFailures')]
            $BackupType,
            $BulkImport = $true,
            $CSVBulkImportFileandFullPathOrigional = "\\TRI-DC01\CreateADUsers$\CSV\Exchange\BulkBackupExchangeUserOrigional.csv",
            $CSVBulkImportFileandFullPath = "\\TRI-DC01\CreateADUsers$\CSV\Exchange\BulkBackupExchangeUser.csv",
            $RenameCSVBulkImportFileandFullPath = "\\TRI-DC01\CreateADUsers$\History\BulkExchangeUser-Backuped-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).csv",
            $MailboxBackupLocation = "\\it-fs02\pst$"

        )

    #'Inbox','SentItems','DeletedItems','Calendar','Contacts','Drafts','Journal','Tasks','Notes','JunkEmail','CommunicationHistory','Voicemail','Fax','Conflicts','SyncIssues','LocalFailures','ServerFailures'

    InitilizeLogging -LogFileRequest $LogFileRequest
    InitilizationAD
    InitilizeExchange

    Function Backup-TheMailBox
    {
        Param
        ( 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [ValidateSet('Full','Inbox','SentItems','DeletedItems','Calendar','Contacts','Drafts','Journal','Tasks','Notes','JunkEmail','CommunicationHistory','Voicemail','Fax','Conflicts','SyncIssues','LocalFailures','ServerFailures')]
            $BackupType,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $MailBox,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $MailboxBackupLocation
        )
            Switch ($BackupType)
                {
                'Full' 
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(FULL).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -FilePath "$MailboxBackupLocation\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(FULL).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -FilePath "$MailboxBackupLocation\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(FULL)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }

                'Contacts' 
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CONTACTS).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Contacts#" -FilePath "$MailboxBackupLocation\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CONTACTS).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Contacts#" -FilePath "$MailboxBackupLocation\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CONTACTS)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }

                 'SentItems' 
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SENTITEMS).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#SentItems#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SENTITEMS).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#SentItems#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SENTITEMS)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }

                'Inbox'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(INBOX).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Inbox#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(INBOX).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Inbox#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(INBOX)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'DeletedItems'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(DELETEDITEMS).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#DeletedItems#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(DELETEDITEMS).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#DeletedItems#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(DELETEDITEMS)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'Calendar'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CALENDAR).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Calendar#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CALENDAR).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Calendar#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CALENDAR)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'Drafts'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(DRAFTS).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Drafts#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(DRAFTS).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Drafts#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(DRAFTS)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'Journal'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(JOURNAL).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Journal#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(JOURNAL).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Journal#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(JOURNAL)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'Tasks'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(TASKS).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Tasks#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(TASKS).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Tasks#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(TASKS)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'Notes'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(NOTES).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Notes#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(NOTES).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Notes#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(NOTES)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'JunkEmail'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(JUNKEMAIL).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#JunkEmail#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(JUNKEMAIL).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#JunkEmail#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(JUNKEMAIL)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'CommunicationHistory'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(COMMUNICATIONHISTORY).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#CommunicationHistory#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(COMMUNICATIONHISTORY).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#CommunicationHistory#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(COMMUNICATIONHISTORY)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'Voicemail'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(VOICEMAIL).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Voicemail#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(VOICEMAIL).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Voicemail#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(VOICEMAIL)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'Fax'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(FAX).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Fax#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(FAX).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Fax#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(FAX)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'Conflicts'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CONFLICTS).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Conflicts#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CONFLICTS).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#Conflicts#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(CONFLICTS)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'SyncIssues'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SYNCISSUES).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#SyncIssues#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SYNCISSUES).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#SyncIssues#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SYNCISSUES)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'LocalFailures'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(LOCALFAILURES).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#LocalFailures#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(LOCALFAILURES).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#LocalFailures#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(LOCALFAILURES)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
                'ServerFailures'
                    {
                        if (!(Test-Path "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SERVERFAILURES).pst"))
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#ServerFailures#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SERVERFAILURES).pst" 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name -IncludeFolders "#ServerFailures#" -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailbox.Database)-$($Mailbox.DisplayName)-$($Mailbox.Alias)-(SERVERFAILURES)-$((get-date).toString(‘yyyyMMdd-HHmmss’)).pst" 
                        }
                    }
    }
    }
    #$baseou = "OU=Companies,DC=triangle,DC=com"

    #$MyDisabledUsers = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $baseou -AccountDisabled | select name
    #$MyListOfDisabledUsersThatHaveMailboxes = foreach ($mbx in $MyDisabledUsers) {Get-Mailbox  $mbx.name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
    #foreach ($Mailboxes in $MyListOfDisabledUsersThatHaveMailboxes) { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailboxes -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailboxes.Database)-$($Mailboxes.DisplayName)-$($Mailboxes.Alias).pst" }

    #

    If ($BulkImport)
    {
        $CSVfile = Import-Csv $CSVBulkImportFileandFullPath 
        foreach ($row in $CSVfile)
        {
            $MailBoxIdentity = $row.GivenName + ' ' + $row.Surname
            If (Verify-UserHasMailbox -UsersAMAccountName $MailBoxIdentity)
            {
                $Mailbox = get-mailbox $MailBoxIdentity #'Michael George'
                Backup-TheMailBox -BackupType $BackupType -MailBox $Mailbox -MailboxBackupLocation $MailboxBackupLocation

                #Backup Options:
                #https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/exchange-server-2010-windows-powershell-managing-mailboxes
                #New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox User1 -IncludeFolders "#Contacts#" -filepath \\server\share\user1.pst
                #New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox testuser -IncludeFolders "Sent Items" -FilePath \\contoso-ex01\export\testuser_sent.pst -ExcludeDumpster
                #New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox testuser -ContentFilter {Received -lt "09/01/2010"} -FilePath \\contoso-ex01\export\testuser_archive.pst -ExcludeDumpster -IsArchive
                #

            }

               # Do
                #{
                    #Write-Progress -Activity "Mailbox Backup:" -PercentComplete (Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics).PercentComplete -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    #"Mailbox Backup: $((Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics).PercentComplete)%" # -NoNewLine
                    #start-sleep 5
                    #cls
                #}
                #Until ( (Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailbox.Name | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics).PercentComplete -eq 100)

        }

     }
     Else
     {
        If (Verify-UserHasMailbox -UsersAMAccountName $MailBoxIdentity)
        {
            $Mailbox = get-mailbox $MailBoxIdentity #'Michael George'
            Backup-TheMailBox -BackupType $BackupType -MailBox $Mailbox -MailboxBackupLocation $MailboxBackupLocation
        }
     }



    End-ExchangeCleanup

    do
    {
    $i = 1
    }
    Until (!(Test-FileLock -Path $CSVBulkImportFileandFullPath))

     Move-Item -Path $CSVBulkImportFileandFullPath -Destination $RenameCSVBulkImportFileandFullPath -Force 
    Copy-Item -Path $CSVBulkImportFileandFullPathOrigional -Destination $CSVBulkImportFileandFullPath
    "COMPLETED PROCESSING FILE: $RenameCSVBulkImportFileandFullPath" | Add-Content $Logfile.LogFile

}
```

Like I said just to backup the mailbox this works great... but I really need it to not complete the function until the mailbox has been backed up completely so the next step can safely delete the account.

Lastly if it can show progression that would be great.

Comment: any suggestion on how to make the script function to wait until all mailboxes are 100% complete in their backup, before closing out the function and doing something else.